# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: crashed

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to open Edge browser using selenium java code.

```java
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));

if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    tlDriver.set(new ChromeDriver());
} else if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    tlDriver.set(new FirefoxDriver());
} else if (browser.equals("InternetExplorerDriver")) {
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
    tlDriver.set(new EdgeDriver(chromeOptions));
} else {
    System.out.println("Please pass the correct browser value: " + browser);
}
```

after i will got issue

```
@sanity
Scenario Outline: MYTIP - Customer JTG Scenario                    # src/test/java/features/Features/sanity.feature:22
Starting Microsoft Edge WebDriver 103.0.1264.77 (2b250f2585e4f7418e51e230b93685cdc0ed9db5) on port 62823
To submit feedback, report a bug, or suggest new features, please visit https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver

Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://aka.ms/WebDriverSecurity for suggestions on keeping Microsoft Edge WebDriver safe.

Microsoft Edge WebDriver was started successfully.
[1660649521.964][WARNING]: Deprecated Microsoft Edge option is ignored: useAutomationExtension
[1660649521.965][WARNING]: Deprecated Microsoft Edge option is ignored: useAutomationExtension
      org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'EQ-EQ6296022', ip: '10.225.5.135', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {ms:edgeOptions: {args: [], binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., excludeSwitches: [enable-automation], extensions: [], useAutomationExtension: false}}, Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., excludeSwitches: [enable-automation], extensions: [], useAutomationExtension: false}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., excludeSwitches: [enable-automation], extensions: [], useAutomationExtension: false}, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [], binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., excludeSwitches: [enable-automation], extensions: [], useAutomationExtension: false}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:558)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:59)
    at qa.factory.DriverFactory.init_driver(DriverFactory.java:62)
    at stepDefinations.Hooks.launchBrowser(Hooks.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

please retry once with below options also

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

More Info on this
[WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50642913#50642913)